# Cast column as different types in same call

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

I've got a table called bundle_metadata containing two columns 'name' and 'value'. I want the value column to contain all sorts of datatypes depending on what kind of metadata is stored. In lack of a better solution I solve this by storing it as varchar.

So for instance a row could be `name: 'Price', value: '1000'` and another: `name: 'Category', value: 'Home'` and a third `name: 'LocationLat', value: '55.15813'`.

Now for the problem:

A select statement could then be:

```
SELECT * FROM [bundle_metadata] WHERE (name='Price' AND value BETWEEN 200 AND 3000) OR (name='Category' AND value = 'Home')
```

Both of the calls works by themselves, but when in combination like above, i get this error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '55.158313' to data type int.
```

**Note**: the value `55.158313` isnt even from the selected rows. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sure it is. you're using the `value` field in your where column, and mysql is STILL trying to convert all those values to ints for the `between` call, even though it should have been excluded by short-circuit evaluation when `name='Price'` failed.

Comment: @MarcB How does that work, if the query itself works fine like so:
`SELECT * FROM [bundle_metadata] WHERE (name='Price' AND value BETWEEN 200 AND 3000)` 
It only fails when done in combination with the second half of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL:
Use condition ' column_name >0 ' this return only numerical value

```
SELECT * FROM `[bundle_metadata]` WHERE (value> 0 ) AND (name='Price' AND cast(value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) BETWEEN 200 AND 3000) OR (name='Category' AND value = 'Home')
```

In MS SQL :
Use ISNUMERIC() method to get rows where the specified column has only numerical  values.

MS SQL Query 1:

```
SELECT *  FROM  [bundle_metadata]  where (ISNUMERIC(value) =1    AND (name='Price' AND CONVERT(FLOAT,[value]) BETWEEN 200 AND 3000))  OR (name='Category' AND value = 'Home')
```

MS SQL Query 2:

```
 SELECT * INTO #temp FROM   [bundle_metadata]  where ISNUMERIC(value) =1 
 SELECT * INTO #final FROM #temp WHERE (name='Price' AND CONVERT(FLOAT,[value]) BETWEEN 200 AND 3000)    
 INSERT INTO #final SELECT * FROM bundle_metadata WHERE (name='Category' AND value = 'Home') 
 SELECT * FROM #final
```

Here the explaination for my second  Query
Line 1: I stored the filtered rows in temp table #temp which has only numerical data in [value] column.
Line 2: Again filter the #temp table by where name ='Price' and apply the                                                              range filtering by converting [value] column into float.then stored in #final table.
Line 3: Insert row which meet the condition where (name='Category' AND value = 'Home') from bundle_metadata into #final table.
Line 4: Get expected result by select the #final table

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @Ajean sorry for unexplained code,now i give the explaination

Comment: The above MSSQL Query 1 works perfectly. BUT:
If i change it to cast to INT instead of float i get the same error as before.

`SELECT *  FROM  [bundle_metadata]  where (ISNUMERIC(value) =1    AND (name='Price' AND CONVERT(INT,[value]) BETWEEN 200 AND 3000))  OR (name='Category' AND value = 'Home')`

INT is a numeric value as well, so why is this not working? The prices '200' and '3000' could go as ints, right?

Comment: Because one of value field contain the  value '55.158313' which reflect the float value,if u want convert it as integer, use round method CONVERT(int,ROUND(value,0)).

Answer (score 0):

You want to do the comparisons as numbers.  In MySQL, you can use silent conversion to convert them:

```
SELECT *
FROM [bundle_metadata]
WHERE (name = 'Price' AND value + 0.0 BETWEEN 200 AND 3000) OR
      (name = 'Category' AND value = 'Home')
```

MySQL has to process the `WHERE` clause for every row.  So, every row is going to be exposed to the conversion.  It decides that the right type for the conversion is an integer, and the floating point value fails that test.

Comment: BTW why it is also not working ? I have defined name and value varchar(50) and getting this error 'Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.'